# How to Supply a Dynamically Built MVC3 MasterPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to use a static html page as an MVC3 razor masterpage.

It needs to be able to inject the controller's razor-built view into a specified span tag on the static html page.

How do i go about:

1. Load the static html
2. Parse the static html string to the point where i need to inject the razor-view
3. Inject the razor view.

Here's the reason why-- a client of ours wants to be able to publish static html (daily) from their CMS and have the application pick up on the "template" and use it for they dynamic sections of their site. They do not have any understanding of .NET and MVC3 and I can not have them interacting in any way with .NET and such.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use a normal MVC3 layout and view.  Honestly, if we knew more about why you wanted to do this, we might be able to help better.

Comment: Is there only one part in the .html that you need to inject your controller action result to? Or you do you need to inject dynanmic content into multiple parts of the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only need to inject your view into one part of the HTML, you can chop the HTML into "before" and "after" pieces. Create a Layout.cshtml that has "before", "middle", and "after" sections. before & after are the parts you parsed from the .html, and middle is the result from your Razor view.

Answer (score 0):

Static pages aren't executed by the server, so if the requirement is to import a dynamic page into a static page, your best bet will be to use an iframe or javascript to place the generated html from the mvc3 site on the page.

You can do this using jQuery pretty easily:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ContentFromMVCSite").load("http://mysite.com/url/to/mvc/view");
});

<div id="ContentFromMVCSite"></div>
```

This code will download the html output from the mvc site and place it inside the div.  For more information [see the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).